# Why is destructuring and concatenation leaving different types of undefined in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, destructor

Here is my code

```
console.log(this.state.pins);
this.setState({ pins: [...this.state.pins, ...block] });
console.log(this.state.pins);
```

Here is what we see in the console...

[image]

[image]

More experementation... When I set my code to this.

```
this.setState({pins: this.state.pins.concat(block)});
```

[image]

So here I am using a `map` function.

```
{pins.map(pin => <PinnedBlock blockId={pin} /> )}
```

When I use the above map function on this array:

```
this.setState({ pins: [...this.state.pins, ...block] });
```

I get a `<PinnedBlock blockId={pin} />`  where `pin` is undefined.

When I use the above map function on this array:

```
this.setState({pins: this.state.pins.concat(block)});
```

I do not get an output corresponding to undefined.

Can someone explain help me understand what is happening here?

Comment: Can you show what `setState` does?

Comment: That is built into `react`. All it really does is update an object `this.state` while performing some magic behind the scenes to keep the view up to date

Comment: In that case, are you sure that `block` doesn't contain an `undefined` element?

Comment: I will double check that.

Comment: It means that `this.state.pins.length` was `1` for some reason. Are you using   `delete` somewhere else?

Comment: I need to do more experimentation to see where undefined is coming from, but I rephrased the question to be more specific about the behavior of undefined.